# Read \r sent by serial port in C#?

Tags: c#, if-statement, serial-port, newline

I'm sending a text by serial port to C#. This text contains \r and it will become a new line in HyperTerminal. Now I want to read this \r in C#. How can I do this?

```
    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        RxString = serialPort1.ReadLine();

        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));
    }

    private void DisplayText(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = RxString;

        if(str == "\r")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This is a new line");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you *only* need to use `\r` as a line separator? If so, just set the `NewLine` property.

Comment: No, I can use \n\r too. But \r works perfectly.

Comment: I used if(str == Enviroment.newline) but it doesn't work.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood me - do you need to spot "\n" as a line separator? Note that `ReadLine` will never return the line separator itself. It returns the line of text.

Comment: maybe str.contains('\r') would do the trick

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `ReadLine()` it will read to the line escape, this can be \r, \n or \r\n so by using the `ReadLine()`command you are automatically detecting your carriage return and removing it from the read string

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

if for some reason you need to preserve the carriage return then you can use the `Read()` command

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ath1fht8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx